# Python - How to insert NULL mysql values

Tags: python, sql

I'm generating a sql file with insert statements with a python script, but I don't know how to insert NULL values.

I have a dictionary where keys are the name of the columns and the values the values I want to insert.
For example:

```
d = {"column1":"1", "column2":"test", "column3":None}
```

Then I want to use that values in my insert statement.

```
sqlfile.write("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('" + d["column1"] + "', '" + d["column2"] + "', '" + d["column3"] + "')")
```

But this will return an error because non type and strings cannot be concatenated and if I replace None by 'NULL' it will insert a 0 in database.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why did you put quotes around the NULL then? `sqlfile.write("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('1','test', NULL)")` inserts an actual NULL.

Comment: Sorry @MartijnPieters I did not explain well. The question was edited :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are inserting the *string* `'NULL'`, not the `NULL` value. If these values are coming from a Python structure, you need to use something else to map to the `NULL` value in SQL.

You could use `None` for this, and only quote other values:

```
def sqlquote(value):
    """Naive SQL quoting

    All values except NULL are returned as SQL strings in single quotes,
    with any embedded quotes doubled.

    """
    if value is None:
         return 'NULL'
    return "'{}'".format(str(value).replace("'", "''"))

sql = "INSERT INTO test VALUES ({column1}, {column2}, {column3})".format(
    **{k: sqlquote(v) for k, v in d.items()})
```

Note that because you have to handle `None` differently, you also have to handle proper SQL quoting! If any of your values directly or indirectly come from user-supplied data, you'd be open for SQL injection attacks otherwise.

The above `sqlquote()` function *should* suffice for [SQLite strings](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue), which follow standard SQL quoting rules. Different databases have different rules for this, so *tripple check your documentation*.

Personally, I'd use the [SQLAlchemy library](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to generate SQL and have *it* handle quoting for you. You can configure it to produce SQL for different database engines.

Comment: Sorry @MartijnPieters I did not explain well. The question was edited :)

Comment: @F.Rita: no, you didn't. That was a rather big detail you omitted. Updated.

Comment: Add `sqlfile.write(sql)` to write out the resulting string.